# Extract all next pages from website with Scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to scrape all the pages from this URL: https://www.residentialpeople.com/za/property-for-sale/cape-town/?country=za&listing_type=residential&transaction_type=sale&longitude=18.49144&latitude=-33.98983&size_qualifier=square_feet&location_slug=cape-town&sort_by=closest_to_farthest&offset=0&limit=10&active=1&_radius_expansion=0&_location=Cape%20Town,%20South%20Africa&status_available_only=0

However, it only manages to scrape the first 4 pages and then it stops
Here is the code:

```
    def parse(self, response):
        # follow links to property pages
        for href in response.xpath('//div[@class="listings-item-bottom"]//a[@class="link link--minimal"]/@href').getall():
            yield response.follow(href, self.parse_property)

        # follow pagination links
        old_offset = self.page_counter
        old_offset = str(old_offset) + '0' if old_offset != 0 else str(old_offset)

        try:
            max_page = int(''.join(response.css('div.custom-pagination-select::text').re(r'\d+')))
        except:
            max_page = None

        self.page_counter += 1
        if self.page_counter < max_page:
            new_offset = str(self.page_counter) + '0'

            next_page_url = response._get_url().replace(f'offset={old_offset}', f'offset={new_offset}')
            next_page = response.urljoin(next_page_url)
            yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions on what can be wrong here?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the only thing you need to replace is the offset in the URL to get to the next page.

Obviously you may want to generalise this, so that you can always get every page based on how many results per search.

### Code Example

```
def parse(self,response):
    for href in response.xpath('//div[@class="listings-item-bottom"]//a[@class="link link--minimal"]/@href').getall():
        yield response.follow(href, self.parse_property)
    
    results_num = int(response.xpath('//div[@class="total-available-results"]/span/text()').get())

    for i in range(10,results_num+10,10):
        url = f'https://www.residentialpeople.com/za/property-for-sale/cape-town/?country=za&listing_type=residential&transaction_type=sale&longitude=18.49144&latitude=-33.98983&size_qualifier=square_feet&location_slug=cape-town&sort_by=closest_to_farthest&offset={i}&limit=10&active=1&status_available_only=0&_radius_expansion=0&_location=Cape%20Town,%20South%20Africa'
        yield scrapy.Request(url=url, callback=self.parse,dont_filter=True)
```

### Explanation

`results_num` gives us the total number of properties. We use a for loop starting from an offset of 10, up to 15720 in this case, remember we need to add +10 to the end argument as the end argument in range does not include up to `results_num`. The step argument of 10 is what we want.

We create the URL dynamically per request, using f-strings in a for loop, we give the variable `i` the value we want explained above. We can use it to create the new string URL for the offset we want per iteration of the for loop. We can then make a request per iteration with the call back to parse function. Remember because the base of the URL is the same, scrapy will filter this, so within the `Request` we specify `dont_filter=True`

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your explanation! 
When I try this, I still only get few properties scraped, instead of all properties from 1572 pages..Can something else be the problem? @AaronS

Comment: Forgot to add the yield statement sorry about that! Code updated.

Comment: You're welcome! If you haven't used f-strings before, I'd highly recommend them! Not as useful for changing multiple variables in a string but were introduced in python 3.6 as format was a bit cumbersome. https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/ is useful! Basically made this piece of code a lot easier.

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty nice, haven't seen this before! Thanks again for a great explanation! @AaronS

Comment: I am so sorry to bother you, but maybe you could help me with one last thing:
I can't even seem to get the results from the main page from this website: https://www.myproperty.co.za/search?last=0.5y&coords%5Blat%5D=-33.9248685&coords%5Blng%5D=18.4240553&coords%5Bnw%5D%5Blat%5D=-33.47127&coords%5Bnw%5D%5Blng%5D=18.3074488&coords%5Bse%5D%5Blat%5D=-34.3598061&coords%5Bse%5D%5Blng%5D=19.00467&description=Cape%20Town%2C%20South%20Africa&status=For%20Sale
Sorry to bother you and thanks for your time :) @AaronS

Comment: You should post this in another question saraherceg. Confuses things to answer another question in here. Also gives you an opportunity to lay out exactly what's the issue and what you've attempted so far. As a tiny hint, turn off javascript in your browser. See what happens.

Comment: Just found your new post and have given you a response. Can I suggest you at least post an attempt even if you didn't get anywhere? It's good for your learning to do so. It's a very common thing to deal with dynamic content. You can tell when the page loads up that there's some javascript functionality.